# How to continually call a REST service using non blocking code with Akka

Tags: scala, akka, throttling

I'm accessing data from a REST endpoint :

```
"https://api-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com/products/BTC-EUR/ticker"
```

To access the data once per second I use an infinite loop `while(true) {` to invoke a message send to the actor once per second which begins the process of invoking the REST request:

The `actor` to access the data is:

```
object ProductTickerRestActor {

  case class StringData(data: String)

}

class ProductTickerRestActor extends Actor {
  
  override def receive: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {

    case ProductTickerRestActor.StringData(data) =>
      try {
        println("in ProductTickerRestActor")
        val rData = scala.io.Source.fromURL("https://api-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com/products/BTC-EUR/ticker").mkString
        println("rData : "+rData)

      }
      catch {
        case e: Exception =>
          println("Exception thrown in ProductTickerRestActor: " + e.getMessage)
      }

    case msg => println(s"I cannot understand ${msg.toString}")
  }
}
```

I start the application using:

```
object ExchangeModelDataApplication {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val actorSystem = ActorSystemConfig.getActorSystem

    val priceDataActor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[ProductTickerRestActor], "ProductTickerRestActor")
    val throttler = Throttlers.getThrottler(priceDataActor)
    while(true) {
      throttler ! ProductTickerRestActor.StringData("test")
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }

}
```

Throttler:

```
object Throttlers {


  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(ActorSystemConfig.getActorSystem)

  def getThrottler(priceDataActor: ActorRef) = Source.actorRef(bufferSize = 1000, OverflowStrategy.dropNew)
    .throttle(1, 1.second)
    .to(Sink.actorRef(priceDataActor, NotUsed))
    .run()
}
```

How to run the following code asynchronously instead of blocking using an infinite loop? :

```
throttler ! ProductTickerRestActor.StringData("test")
Thread.sleep(1000)
```

Also, the throttler, in this case, maybe redundant as I'm throttling requests within the loop regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use Akka Streams for this along with Akka HTTP.  Using Akka 2.6.x, something along these lines would be sufficient for 1 request/second

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._

import scala.concurrent.duration._

object HTTPRepeatedly {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  import system.dispatcher

  val sourceFromHttp: Source[String, NotUsed] =
    Source.repeated("test") // Not sure what "test" is actually used for here...
      .throttle(1, 1.second)
      .map { str =>
        HttpRequest(uri = "https://api-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com/products/BTC-EUR/ticker")
      }.mapAsync(1) { req =>
        Http().singleRequest(req)
      }.mapAsync(1)(_.entity.toStrict(1.minute))
      .map(_.data.decodeString(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
}
```

Then you could, for instance (for simplicity, put this in a `main` within `HTTPRepeatedly` so the implicits are in scope etc.)

```
val done: Future[Done] =
  sourceFromHttp
    .take(10) // stop after 10 requests
    .runWith(Sink.foreach { rData => println(s"rData: $rData") })

scala.concurrent.Await.result(done, 11.minute)

system.terminate()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sending a request every second is not a good idea. If, for some reason, the request is delayed, you are going to get a lot of requests piled up. Instead, send the next request one second after the previous requests completes.

Because this code uses a synchronous `GET` request, you can just send the next request one second after `mkString` returns.

But using synchronous requests is not a good way to consume a RESTful API in Akka. It blocks the actor `receive` method until the request is complete, which can eventually block the whole `ActorSystem`.

Instead, use Akka Http and `singleRequest` to perform an asynchronous request.

```
Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "https://api-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com/products/BTC-EUR/ticker"))
```

This returns a `Future`. Make the new request one second after the request completes (e.g. using `onComplete` on the `Future`).

Not only is this safer and more asynchronous, it also provides much more control over the REST API call than `fromUrl`